# Enable G729 codec in linphone for iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

I herewith a problem of enabling G729 codec.

Currently I am using linphone libraries for making sip calls from iPhone. I need to work with g729 codec.

Can anyone has idea on how do i do that? Kindly share your valuable knowledge on that.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you were able to compile the SDK and the linphone XCode project, here is what you need to do:

1. Include G729_preference in the Audio.plist file. You can either type all the info yourself or simply copy the G722 line and simply replace 722 with 729. Make sure you set Default Value to YES
2. In Project -> Target -> Build Settings find "Preprocessor macros" and include HAVE_G729
3. Run the project. The SDP should now include G729 in the invites or 200 OKs.

Note that G729 has royalties (aka patent license) so be aware. If you plan to deploy commercially, you will need to setup an agreement with Sipro.

Comment: hi any help on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15832290/how-to-compile-linphone-for-iphone-couldnt-find-libmediastreamer-base-a-libme

Comment: @pfs Hi Do we need to download codec and install in system or G729 is already in default code? Also Do you know how we can integrate G711 and VPN?

Comment: G729 is already there. G711 is already integrated. Did you mean VP8? For VPN, I don't know.

Comment: I did steps 2 and 3 (first is already implemented), also I've dropped a lib libmsbcg729.a to the target. But I still receive this message: **ortp-warning-Codec G729 is not supported by mediastreamer2, removed.**  The sdk was built with support of GPL third parties and with debug mode on.

Comment: @pfs Which pod version you have configured for G729. I want to integrate the G729 codec in the latest version so can you please help me with that.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the instruction in readme.md included in project.

You need to enable G729 codec with this command:

```
./prepare.py -DENABLE_NON_FREE_CODECS=ON -DENABLE_G729=ON
```