# How to compile Linphone for iPhone ? Couldn't find libmediastreamer_base.a libmediastreamer_voip.a

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, sip, voip

I am trying to compile linphone source code. I've downloaded the code from [Here.](https://www.linphone.org/eng/download/git.html)
When I started the xcode all the libraries are missing. I have installed all ports specified in **README** file.

I did google and got libraries but still I could not find **libmediastreamer_base.a** and **libmediastreamer_voip.a** files.

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you build libraries? 
Go to linphone source folder and enter commands:

```
$ cd submodules/build
$ make all
```

or if you don't want make your project GPL compliant enter this commands instead:

```
$ cd submodules/build
$ make all enable_gpl_third_parties=no
```

This is all written in the README file. I also downloaded linphone source for the same link and I just followed README file. It all worked. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. It seems that the sdk fold is not inclued.

   linphone-sdk/apple-darwin/lib/libmediastreamer_voip.a (and the other)

   You should add this path into your xcode "Build settings" -> "Header search paths"
2. If these 2 files not exist in the folder, which means mediastreamer not compiled.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not downloaded the whole project. So, that it is showing missing files. Please use command terminal for full app downloaded from given below links.

https://www.linphone.org/technical-corner/linphone/downloads