# Making VOIP calls using only G.729 codec in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, voip

This is my first VOIP application.

I am using linphone source code which I downloaded from [here](https://github.com/GargoyleSoftware/voip-client-ios) and I am able to make calls using speex audio codec but i want to make calls using only g.729 codec.
I enabled g.729 codec in my code by following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10648635/enable-g729-codec-in-linphone-for-iphone?rq=1)

But when I try to make call using Only g.729 codec then it is giving error media not supported.

Any help is appreciated.

Please help me in solving this.

Thanks

Comment: Add your source code into your question through [pastebin.](http://www.pastebin.com)

Answer (score 0):

I have achieve that after the flowing step:
1. Build your linphone lib with G.729 codec
2. Load G.729 codec in factory config (code)
3. Set G.729 as default codec (optional)

Comment: can you give us a brief description related to G729 Codec? Currently, we are using the latest version of the linphone and in this not display G729 Codec.

Comment: The G.729 codec is not shipping with default Linphone lib you can download from internet.   If you want to have this codec in your lib, you must find the linphone source, then download all submodules then build the lib by your self