# Linphone iphone G729 Enabling in settings screen but not enabling in Dialing screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

For Linphone iPhone I have enabled g729 codec using this link [Enable G729 codec in linphone for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10648635/enable-g729-codec-in-linphone-for-iphone). It's working fine and seen the g729 codec working fine.

When dialing from home screen it could not enable g729 codec. When move from home screen to settings screen and came back to home screen then dialled a number, g729 codec enabled and call is connecting. For the first time login from home screen call is not connecting and g729 codec was not enabling. Can you suggest an idea how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which pod version you have configured for G729. I want to integrate the G729 codec in the latest version so can you please help me with that.

Answer (score 1):

set `g729_Preference` key to Boolean Value YES in `PhoneMainView.m` file. It will enable g729_Preference whenever application will start.